# "code 400, message Bad request version" errors with react native IOS app

Tags: node.js, xcode, react-native, flask

I have a react native app running on an iphone emulator (xcode)
The app makes api calls to a local flask server (http://127.0.0.1:5000).
The flask server is also deployed on AWS and when the app switches to the remote server it works as intended.
The app works fine on an android emulator (for the local and remote flask server)
I'm using a macbook m1

React native ios node console:

```
 LOG  Running local build
 LOG  localhostUrl: http://127.0.0.1:5000
 ERROR  api error: [TypeError: Network request failed]
 ERROR  failed to fetch user summary: {"type":"userSummary/fetch/rejected","meta":{"requestId":"2hAYW5pj0wlhgG0tGpcPj","rejectedWithValue":false,"requestStatus":"rejected","aborted":false,"condition":false},"error":{"name":"TypeError","message":"Cannot read property 'rejectWithValue' of undefined","stack":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'rejectWithValue' of undefined\n    at handleApi$ (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:639031:68)\n    at call (native)\n    at tryCatch (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:20683:23)\n    at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:20764:32)\n    at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:20708:30)\n    at call (native)\n    at tryCatch (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:20683:23)\n    at invoke (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:20714:30)\n    at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:20721:19)\n    at tryCallOne (/Users/distiller/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:53:16)\n    at anonymous (/Users/distiller/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:139:27)\n    at apply (native)\n    at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:25543:26)\n    at _callTimer (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:25462:17)\n    at _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:25492:17)\n    at callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:25655:44)\n    at __callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:4623:46)\n    at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:4435:45)\n    at __guard (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:4607:15)\n    at flushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:4434:21)\n    at callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.appName:4419:33)"}}
```

Flask console:

```
ERROR:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2023 17:05:38] code 400, message Bad request version ('Æ\x18\x00*')
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2023 17:05:38] "üñí|RþêÂõ%Ãb*k;Â7ûÿU¦dìqá *¯¹Ü¶ØÔzCÞÛ»_^wç´ìkYq·Æ*" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
ERROR:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2023 17:05:38] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ("\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01ü\x03\x03\x12u\x87ß;Ý'ÉîÙ»?nÀ«Ê%sº\x9cÅr\x86fe³\x88&\x92¯\x19\x81")
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2023 17:05:38] "üuß;Ý'ÉîÙ»?nÀ«Ê%sºÅrfe³&¯ (è¯(û4ùwÝsÞÿgT¿IcÕ±qUóreÏ,ªªÀ,À+Ì©À0À/Ì¨À" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
ERROR:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2023 17:05:38] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x16\x03\x01\x00}\x01\x00\x00y\x03\x01NÏÐ®û½à\x84ó_8\x7f:1gg\x15\x8f\x86j]?d\x94Jçìv4î\x00\x14\x00\x00\x14À')
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2023 17:05:38] "}yNÏÐ®û½àó_8:1ggj]?dJçìv4îÀ" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using another emulator (switched from iPhone X to iPhone 14) resolved this issue..